# my flutter app is not fitting in different devices

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-sliver

```
new Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
          color: Colors.black12,
          child: new Row(

            children: <Widget>[
              new Image.asset('images/driver.jpeg',
                  height: 80.0,
                  width:150.0,
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                repeat:ImageRepeat.repeat ,
                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
              ),
              new Image.asset('images/car.png',
                  height: 80.0,
                  width:150.0,
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,

              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

What should be fitting?

If you mean that your `Container` should fill its parent you can set `inifinity` as its height

```
new Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      ...
```

or stretch the cross axis alignment of your `Row`

```
 Row(
     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
     ...
```

Comment: Thanks Zroq for your help.I have come up with problem